# Bypassing a constraint of a goal function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions

I have a goal function $ J(\omega_1,...,\omega_K)$ that I want to maximize with respect to
$$ \omega_1,...,\omega_K$$
and with the following constraint
$$ \sum_{k=1}^K\omega_k = 1$$
But unfortunately, it is very difficult. ( I am using Lagrange multipliers method  )

I was thinking of the following bypass:

1. Maximize my goal function **without** the constraint
2. Sum all $ \omega_1,...,\omega_K$ and divide each $\omega$ by the sum to **force** the costraint.

I was wondering if this is true and if so when.

Any suggestions on how to attack this problem?

Comment: In general, it will not work. You can notice that $\omega_K = 1 - \sum_{j < K} \omega_j,$ and you can maximise freely on the $\omega_j$ for $j < K.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be true if $J(r\omega_1, \ldots, r\omega_K) = J(\omega_1, \ldots, \omega_K)$ for all $r > 0$.

An example where it is not true:
$$J(\omega_1, \omega_2) = \exp(-((\omega_1-3)^2 + \omega_2^2)) - \exp(-((\omega_1-1)^2 + \omega_2^2)) .$$
$J(\omega_1, \omega_2)$ is a differentiable function, and it can be verified that $J(\omega_1, \omega_2)$ is maximized at $(\omega_1, \omega_2) = (3, 0)$ and minimized at $(\omega_1, \omega_2) = (1, 0)$. So, maximizing $J(\omega_1, \omega_2)$ without restriction and then dividing the maximizer $\omega_1, \omega_2$ by $(\omega_1 + \omega_2)$ to obtain the constrained maximizer would not work here. A contour plot of this example function $J(\omega_1, \omega_2)$ is given below ($\omega_1$ on the horizontal axis and $\omega_2$ on the vertical axis).[image]